# Reference operator and shared_ptr C++11 misunderstanding

Tags: c++, state, shared-ptr

I'm trying to level-up my C++ knowledge and need help in understanding some of the constructions with reference pointers and `shared_ptr`.

I have a construction like this:

```
IState *m_Loader;

void CStateManager::AttachState(E_STATE _estate, const IState &_state)
{
switch(_estate)
{
case STATE_LOADER:
    m_Loader = _state;
    break;
}
}
```

Compiler tells me that it cant convert "`Const IState` to `IState*`" - how could I save the object, so I could use it later? I'm trying to free myself from pointers of old C-language and use modern C++.

The second question is how I can use a `shared_ptr` to implement a State Pattern? As I see it is not reliable to use `shared_ptr` and possibly I need `weak_ptr`, but still I can't imagine how to implement such thing.

Full source code here, to understand what I'm trying to implement.

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class IState;

class IStateManager
{
public:
    enum E_STATE
    {
    STATE_LOADER,
    STATE_MENU,
    STATE_GAME,
    STATE_EXIT
    };

virtual void SwitchState(E_STATE _estate) = 0;
virtual void AttachState(E_STATE _estate, const IState &_state) = 0;
virtual void Update() = 0;

public:
virtual ~IStateManager() {}
};

class IState
{
public:
virtual void Enter(const IStateManager &_statemgr) = 0;
virtual void Exit() = 0;
virtual void Sleep() = 0;
virtual void Update() = 0;

public:
virtual ~IState() {}
};

class CStateManager: public IStateManager
{
public:
void SwitchState(E_STATE _estate);
void AttachState(E_STATE _estate, const IState &_state);
void Update();
~CStateManager();
private:
IState *m_Loader;
IState *m_Menu;
IState *m_Game;
IState *m_Exit;
};
;
void CStateManager::SwitchState(E_STATE _estate)
{

}

void CStateManager::AttachState(E_STATE _estate, const IState &_state)
{
switch(_estate)
{
case STATE_LOADER:
    m_Loader = _state;
    break;
case STATE_MENU:

    break;
case STATE_GAME:

    break;
case STATE_EXIT:

    break;

}
}

void CStateManager::Update()
{

}

CStateManager::~CStateManager()
{

}
```

Comment: The variable `m_Loader` is a *pointer* to an `IState` object, while `_state` is a *reference* to an `Istate` object. You have bigger problems though than creating an expression that turns `_state` to a pointer, and that is that you can't save a pointer to an argument (or other local non-static variable) as it will go out of scope once the function returns. Maybe pass it as a pointer instead?

Comment: The modern C++ smart pointers are all about *ownership*.  Which class *owns* the pointers in your code? Which class is merely borrowing the reference?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, thank you for your reply. Should i use pointers instead of references and stop screwing around?

Comment: nneonneo, Ownership, what is ment by this? Im not natively english-speaker, so i cant understand what do you mean by ownership. IState object is created outside of this two classes, but passed to a CStateManager to controll this IState object.

Comment: pass a pointer of IState to your function `AttachState`, and not a const.

Comment: Or remove 'const'. A reference can't be a const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big concern here is the lifetime of the object that you are referencing, and you can get in trouble with that whether you use a reference, a raw pointer, or a `shared_ptr`, for example:

```
CStateManager test()
{
    CStateManager result;
    IState localIState;

    result.AttachState( CStateManager::STATE_LOADER, localIState );
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    CStateManager badLoader = test();
    return 0;
}
```

In the `main` function if `badLoader::m_Loader` is ever accessed there will be a segfault, because the m_Loader is a pointer to a memory location that no longer exists. The same thing would obviously be true if `m_Loader` was a reference, or even a `shared_ptr`.

How you would avoid the segfault is by using `m_Loader` as a `weak_ptr`. So your code would change like this:

```
std::weak_ptr< IState > m_Loader;

void CStateManager::AttachState(E_STATE _estate, std::weak_ptr< IState > _state)
{
    switch(_estate)
    {
    case STATE_LOADER:
        m_Loader = _state;
        break;
    }
}
```

In the calling function you would also have to change how you created `localIState`:

```
CStateManager test()
{
    CStateManager result;
    std::shared_ptr< IState > localIState( new IState );

    result.AttachState( CStateManager::STATE_LOADER, localIState );
    return result;
}
```

This will protect you from segfaulting if you access `badLoader::m_Loader` in `main`, because a `std::weak_ptr` will always check it's target's existence before accessing.